# How to search for similar string in DataTable

Tags: c#

I want to be able to detect 2 similar strings in my datatable. How do I do that?

```
foreach (DataRow row2 in visualDataTable.Rows)                    
{
    foreach (char server in serverName)
    {
       foreach(similar string in servername)
       {
          // do something..
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you define "similar"?

Comment: KKW and KKW strings

Comment: So if the strings are exactly the same?

Comment: Yeah exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would involve iterating two times through your rows and compare each value with one and another (similar to your above approach):

```
foreach (DataRow row in visualDataTable.Rows)                    
{
    foreach (DataRow compareRow in visualDataTable.Rows))
    {
        if(row["<your column>"] == compareRow["<your column>"])
        {
            // The two rows have the same column value for <your column>
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```